# how to use SHAP library for text classification?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, nlp, pipeline, shap

i have text data and pip line model . i want to using `shap` library to Visualize the impact on all the output classes

i got this error :

```
TypeError: The passed model is not callable and cannot be analyzed directly with the given masker! Model: Pipeline(steps=[('vect1', CountVectorizer()),
                ('tfidf1', TfidfTransformer()), ('clf1', MultinomialNB())])
```

how can i handle it

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
vectorized_data = pipe_model1.named_steps['vect1'].transform(background_data)
transformed_background_data =pipe_model1.named_steps['tfidf1'].transform(vectorized_data)
explainer = shap.KernelExplainer(pipe_model1.named_steps['clf1'].predict_proba, transformed_background_data)
shap_values = explainer.shap_values(transformed_background_data)
```

the `background_data` is your data to use

your using the pipeline model and you should add your pip line model sequensly